# Matching files using python program

Tags: python

I have to two files as follows

```
File1
ids
CID5265
CID7263
CID9289
....

File 2
ids
CID7363  3.5e-06 -3837 
CID5265  4.5      -938
CID9289  8.9      -9873
....
```

I want  compare file1 with file2  to match any ids in file1 is present in file2 if yes  i should print whole line as follows

```
CIDS9289  8.9  -9873
....
```

to acheive this wrote python script as follows

```
infile = open("file1","r")

searchtxt = open("file2.txt","r")

for line in infile.readlines():

    if searchtxt in line:

       print line
```

but i gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finding_words.py", line 7, in <module>
    if searchtxt in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not file
```

I know im doing very simple mistake but not able to figure it out can anybody tell how to solve this..

THanks in advance

NI

Comment: Please remember to accept answers to your questions, by clicking the check mark next to the best one. You haven't done this for any of your questions so far. You should do it for this question, and your old, answered ones too.

Comment: If you're on a Unix system, you should check out `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
print [line for id in searchTxtData for line in inFileData if id.strip() in line]
```

Or using with statement:

```
ids = [id.strip() for id in open("file1.txt","r") if id.strip()]

with open("file2.txt","r") as dataFile:
    for line in dataFile:            
        if line.strip() and line.split()[0] in ids:
           print line
```

Comment: Not very efficient, but should work. A better option: sort the data and use only a loop, iterating on both files.

Comment: Hi i tried using with statment when i execute the program nothing is printing and not even showing any error

Comment: hi again same problem still it doesnt print anything

Comment: Just check to be sure which file contains ids and which one data. I am reading ids from file1 and looking them within file2. If this opposite to what you have just modify my code to use correct file names

Answer (score 2):

```
# Usage: foo.py ID_FILE DATA_FILE

ids = set()
with open(sys.argv[1]) as id_file:
    ids = set(line.strip() for line in id_file)

with open(sys.argv[2]) as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        if line.split()[0] in ids:
            print line,
```

Comment: this. because you should be thinking sets. if you're not comfortable with `with` (when did they introduce that anyway? I never got the hang of it...), you can just do `id_file = open(sys.argv[1])` and try not to forget to close it afterwards. Actually, if you're not comfortable with `with` yet, you should sit down and increment your skills... so, uh, bye, I'm off to read a tutorial :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program fails because `searchtxt` is a file object, not a string. Presumably, you want to add another loop over that file object, checking for the text read from `searchtxt` in `line`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have your search backwards -- instead of looking to see if your line from the first file is in the second, you are asking if the entire second file is in the line from the first file.  You need to loop over the second file, checking to see if the key that starts each line is in the first file data.  Change your code as follows:

```
infile = open("file1","r")

keys = set()
for line in infile:
    break   # skip first line
for line in infile:
    keys.add(line.strip())   # get rid of trailing newline

searchtxt = open("file2.txt","r")

for line in searchtxt:
    break   # skip first line
for line in searchtxt:
    key, rest = line.split(' ', 1)
    if key in keys:
        print line
```